# How to automatically resize renderwindow in VTK?

Tags: c++, resize, vtk

I want to  resize automatically renderwindow in VTK. But I could not find any appoarch to solve it. Who know? Help me!

Answer (score 2):

`vtkRenderWindow` inherits virtual `void SetSize(int width, int height)` public method from `vtkWindow`. Size is in screen pixels.